# safari don't load dynamic asset with cross origin in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create an image, add it to the asset system of A-Frame and later use it as a texture on a plane.

Here 2 relevant functions:

```
 function createImage (src, id){                              
     img = new Image();                                   
     img.src = src;                                       
     img.id = id;                                         
     img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";                       
     img.addEventListener('load', function(){             
         console.log('load: '+src);                   
     });                                                  
     img.addEventListener('error', function(){            
         console.log('error: '+src);                  
     });                                                  
     document.querySelector('a-assets').appendChild(img)  
}                                                            

function addImage (plane, id){                               
     plane.setAttribute('material', {src: id});           
}
```

Later I do

```
var pathToImage = 'https://stuff.amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg';
var planeEntity = document.getElementById('myplane');

createImage(pathToImage, 'myuniqueid');
addImage(planeEntity, '#myuniqueid'); //< errors fires here
```

Errors logs are not very useful. The first say

"THREE.WebGLState: -SecurityError: The operation is insecure"

The second and the 255 others are things with mipmap and texture power-of-2 respectively. I think that last errors are fired because the texture is not loaded.

**Relevant info:**

- Using aframe-v0.8.2
- Using safari 11.1
- image example is 1024x1024
- image example is in an amazon web service (AWS)
- I test with two images, one with public permissions and another with private permissions (can access only one domain, where I test)
- code work fine without any error in firefox 60.0.2 and chrome 67.0.3396.87 (both in windows), and work fine in same chrome version in mac.

No relevant info:

- code don't work in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 (security error)

**Curiosity:**

if image is added to code directly like this

```
<img id="myuniqueid" src='https://stuff.amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg' crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it work! but I need to add image dynamically

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured CORS in AWS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

With the information provided putting your image in assets does not give you much value. Probably easier to do:

`planeEl.setAttribute('material', {src: 'https://stuff.amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg'});`

Comment: it work in firefox and chrome, I think that AWS config is ok.
add the path directly fires "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error (note: diferent to Security error in question). the image is added to asset because can be used many times